# Apache Camel and Hystrix Command Name

Tags: apache-camel, hystrix

I'm really happy to see hystrix support though DSL in a latest Apache Camel version 2.18.0. My question is - how does one name a hystrix command now?

Let's say if I write -

```
from("direct:start").hystrix().to("log:out")
```

Hystrix dashboard will register "hystrix1" command and show stat for it, that's the point I wanna change.

Apache Camel's doc says - "CommandKey - Used to identify the hystrix command. This option cannot be configured but is locked down to be the node id to make the command unique.". In their code I see them using a route's naming strategy so it's probably somewhat customizable, I just couldn't figure out how.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We made it use the node id as the command name. So you can try
using `id` to set the node id:

```
hystrix().id("myNameHere")
   ...
```